# IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property + manuall ids

Tags: hibernate, persistence

I have two entities that are bounded by one-2-one assosiation: Person <-> Address. Address PK in the same time is FK for Person's PK. So Address get it's PK from Person table.

***My code:***

```
newPerson.setId(10); //in this case I must to set id manually
newAddress.setId(10); //in this case I must to set id manually
newPerson.set(newAdress);
newAddress.set(newPerson);
newPerson = (Person) session.merge(newPerson); //EXCEPTION! But session.saveOrUpdate(profile) works fine. Why?
```

**But  I use sequence_generator for Person and Address entity!**

***It throws:***

*IdentifierGenerationException: attempted to assign id from null one-to-one property*

**Question:**

*What is the reason? As I understand - Hibernate doesn't accept my manually ID's.
Why merge doesn't work, but save works fine? As I understand merge has a more wide functionality than save.*